# Значения на графике в Grafana отличаются от реальных

Tags: prometheus, grafana, метрики

Я хочу построить график отношения сигнал/шум (SNR). Мое приложение на C++ измеряет значения SNR и передает эти значения в Grafana 8.5 с помощью библиотеки prometheus-spp. Значения на графике в Grafana не соответствуют реальным значениям.

Мое приложение на C++ измеряет значения сигнал/шум (SNR) и передает эти значения в Grafana с помощью библиотеки prometheus-spp. Поскольку значения SNR могут быть отрицательными, я использую счетчик Gauge.

Мой запрос выглядит примерно так:

`idelta(MyApp_gauge{Channel_type="Main",Metric_name="SNR_average",Channel_index="0"}[1m])`

В итоге при реальных значениях SNR около 18 я получаю на графике значение около 45.

[image: grafana scale]

Может быть, я должен сделать запрос по-другому? Если да, то как?

Comment: А какие у вас исходные значения в этой метрике, без idelta?

Comment: @andreymal, на счетчик counter.Increment(snr) приходят значения около 18, а в Графане отображается примерно 45. Если использовать функцию delta(), то значения около 180

Comment: Что такое counter.Increment и при чём тут инкремент вообще?

Comment: @andreymal, counter.Increment() - это функция библиотеки prometheus-cpp для сбора данных.

Comment: Окей, а зачем здесь инкремент-то? По тексту вопроса не похоже, чтобы вам надо было что-то инкрементировать

Comment: Да и вообще — почему counter, если в тексте вопроса вы написали про gauge? Если я правильно понимаю суть, то было бы логичнее использовать [Gauge Set](https://jupp0r.github.io/prometheus-cpp/classprometheus_1_1Gauge.html#af73681eff59786a4072b18c9404ea062) наверное?

Comment: @andreymal, каждое новое значение складывается с предыдущим - это основа сбора данных в Prometheus. А функция delta() в Графане приводит данные в исходное состояние

Comment: Вас очень сильно обманули, никто не заставляет складывать значения в Prometheus, нет такой основы

Comment: Я так понимаю, ваша главная проблема в том, что вы перепутали gauge и counter, а дальше сделали из этого слишком далеко идущие выводы и ввели в заблуждение сами себя. Удалите всю эту метрику к чертям, избавьтесь от counter, заново создайте нормальный Gauge и делайте нормальный Set без всяких инкрементов и дельт

Comment: Возможно, я сам раздуплялся, может и не туда свернул. Т.е. использовать Set() для формирования вектора значений. А в ГРафане какой запрос?

Comment: Если ваша задача — увидеть в точности те значения, которые вы запихнули в Set, то просто выкиньте idelta и [1m] да и всё

Comment: @andreymal, проверил - так действительно работает. Спасибо!